# Android WebView opens it shows [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:663 error in Logcat

Tags: android, webview

When WebView got visible it continuously shows `[AUX]` error. The full error shown as

```
E/GPUAUX: [AUX]GuiExtAuxCheckAuxPath:663: Null anb
```

Can anyone please help me to find the cause of this issue?.

Thanks!

Comment: this same issue also occurs when banner ads get loaded.

Comment: Same issue when full ad is loaded?!

Comment: Does anyone know what causes this when admob ads are loaded?

Answer (score 1):

**step 1:-** replace ***http*** => ***https***

**step2:-**
implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.2.1'

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```